# Как ввести данные в массив с клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript

Товарищи! Как мне ввести элементы в массив с клавиатуры? Мне нужно что бы данные задавались с клавиатуры а не изначально.

```js
let n = [1, -1, 2, 3, -3, 4, 5]; //<- Как?

nSorted = n.sort();
 
count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  if (n[i + 1] - n[i] <= 2) {
    i++;
    count++;
  } else {
    count++;
  }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуемся prompt и циклом. 
В каждой итерации цикла будет добавлять данные в массив, преобразуя к числу

```js
const cnt = prompt('Сколько будем вводить?');

const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i< Number(cnt); i++) {
  arr.push(+prompt(`Введите ${i+1} номер`))
}

console.log(arr)
```

Преобразование строки к числу, можно выполнить следующими функциями:

- Number()
- parseInt()
- добавив **+** к строковой переменной